# gdstorage config is throwing error; Django

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api

**MySettings**

```
from decouple import config
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE = config("GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE_CONTENTS")
```

I'm trying to setup gdstorage for my django project but was not given a json file according to the instruction in the docs so i copied the keys and placed it in my environmental variable yet it's still throwing this error.

**MyErrorMessage**

```
    gd_storage = GoogleDriveStorage()
  File "C:\Users\username\.virtualenvs\vicsite-3EqYD9rF\lib\site-packages\gdstorage\storage.py", line 160, in __init__
    credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
  File "C:\Users\username.virtualenvs\vicsite-3EqYD9rF\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 238, in from_service_account_file
    info, signer = _service_account_info.from_filename(
  File "C:\Users\username.virtualenvs\vicsite-3EqYD9rF\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_service_account_info.py", line 72, in from_filename
    with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '78a23bb0124ac97ec7404104ae37dccffe33846a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE = None
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE_CONTENTS = config("GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE_CONTENTS")
```

More details are in https://pypi.org/project/django-googledrive-storage/